# Sending an array of strings with restsharp

Tags: arrays, restsharp, freshdesk

I am trying to include a tag when I am calling the Freshdesk outbound_email API, in the API docs it says the type for tags is an array of strings, so I want to send something like ["tag1", "tag2", tag3"] but I am not sure how to add it as a parameter with restsharp.

I have tried doing `request.AddParameter` but it won't accept an array as a parameter.

I have also tried doing JSON convert and then adding it as a parameter but the end point doesn't accept it.

Comment: Exactly how does the documentation state the tags should be represented?  As query parameters?  In the request body, as JSON?

Answer (score 0):

This was confusing for me at first as well, since the Freshdesk API says that tags are a string array. It appears that the `tags[]` parameter only works when sending strings, and not arrays or lists (when sending from `RestSharp` at least)!

The *incorrect* way to set tags, which results in the tag showing up as a `System.String[]` in Freshdesk:

```
List<string> tags = new() { "tag1", "tag2" };
request.AddParameter("tags[]", tags.ToArray());
```

The *correct* way to set tags, which adds a parameter per tag (you can also just reuse the `AddParameter` line for however many you need):

```
List<string> tags = new() { "tag1", "tag2" };
foreach (var tag in tags)
{
    request.AddParameter("tags[]", tag);
}
```